# Is there Outlook 2007-based tool for "public email"?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

One of the things Jeff mentioned in a [recent Coding Horror article](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001302.html) was "Stop. Sending. Email."

The problem is that email is just so darned convenient for everybody, and Outlook certainly makes it even easier.

I'm wondering if anybody has any experience with any tools that try to "split the differece" for work-type discussions that "should" be public (at least with co-workers).  The convenience of email (in Outlook 2007) together with say something like SharePoint lists/discussions.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could [Wave](http://wave.google.com).